# Does jQuery offer an overlay with background fade widget?

Tags: javascript, jquery, modal-dialog

I'm looking for a very common element - I want to pop a modal dialog on top of a web page, and fade out the page in the background until the dialog is dismissed.

Is this functionality offered by jQuery? If not, is there a jQuery compatible widget which many people use for this purpose

Comment: You should start by looking at the jQuery UI, adding the fade out should be simple if it's not already implemented.     http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery UI Dialog will do this for you.

http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal